# How to target a CSS ID to a specific HTML tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this text to center using the following HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            #index_page h1
            {
                text_align:             center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="index_page">
            <h1>
                Summon The Assault
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's not centered in my browser though. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your css on the `text_align : center;` this should be `text-align:center;`

This should fix it

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AdmiralAdama please mark this answer as the correct answer to help other people with the same problem quickly find the solution.